# Not sure how to do binary division

Tags: arithmetic

I saw this question in my textbook:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/82luA.png

It doesn't look right. From what I understand:

110101 into 101000110100000.

110101 can't go into 101000, so you extend it by one, then do 110101 into 1010001, no? I'm confused and I don't understand how to perform this specific question I link to.

Answer (score 2):

If it actually were binary long division, it would look like this:

```
               110001010
       ┌────────────────
110101 │ 101000110100000
        - 110101     
        ────────     
           111001    
         - 110101                  
         ────────    
              1000100
             - 110101
             ────────
                 111100
               - 110101
               ─────────
                    1110
```

(Converted to decimal, this means that 20896 ÷ 53 = 394, remainder 14.)

However, your textbook looks like it's actually doing [CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) "division" which uses bitwise [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) instead of subtraction.  I wish they wouldn't confuse students by calling this operation "division" when it's not.

Comment: Wow, I've been stressing at this for like two hours. Thank you so much, you just saved me for my exam tomorrow, at least for one question. The CRC division is so much easier!

Comment: For what it's worth, this operation _is_ division; it's just division in the ring of polynomials $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ rather than division over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: True.  But it's not the *usual* division operation, and that point confused me when I was in college, just like it confused soju tonight.